# What is the UOM of Microsoft Footprint 2017 height data

Tags: footprint, building-heights

It says on the website that height's unit of measurement of MSFP 2017 is in meters. However, as I looked into some real building examples on Google Map street view, they height looks very inaccurate (seems to make more sense if it's in feet). Here's are some examples:

Coordinates: 36.717682, -119.78708. Height according to MSFP 2017: 10.11 meters (doesn't make sense, 10.11 feet is more reasonable?)
[image]

Coordinates: 36.719514, -119.78763. Height according to MSFP2017: 10.51 m. 
[image]

If you know more accurate building height data sources please let me know.

Comment: Do you have data for a building near you? If so, measure the height of that building and compare it to the Microsoft data (there are youtube tutorials about how to measure the height of a tree or building using shadows and basic algebra, so no need endanger yourself by climbing onto the roof with a measuring tape).

Comment: Thank you, but I am only interested in Fresno City which is not where I'm currently at. Measuring my nearby buildings provides little inference to Fresno City. Do you know any other sources to get building heights from?

Comment: My point was that you can groundtruth the microsoft data by comparing the known height of a nearby building to the height of that same building as reported in their data. That's based on the assumption that their data set shows the same sort of unlikely data for your area as it does for Fresno City. A mixup between meters and feet seems like a very likely mistake, and the 10-ish feet heights seem reasonable for single-story buildings, so it seems reasonable to assume that that's what happened. If you can groundtruth the data as I suggested, that would further support that hypothesis.